# Conda | Could not load library libcudnn_adv_train.so.8

Tags: python, lstm, ray

I am using tensorflow 2.9.1 cuda 11.7 and cudnn 8.5 in conda environment. when I am using ray for LSTM hyper parameter optimization, I got this error

```
(BroadModel pid=145826) Could not load library libcudnn_adv_train.so.8. Error: /home/arman/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/../lib/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8: undefined symbol: _Z22cudnnGenericOpTensorNdILi3EE13cudnnStatus_tP12cudnnContext16cudnnGenericOp_t21cudnnNanPropagation_tPKdPKvPK17cudnnTensorStructS8_S8_SB_S8_S8_SB_Pv, version libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8
(BroadModel pid=145826) *** SIGABRT received at time=1661887480 on cpu 6 ***
(BroadModel pid=145826) PC: @     0x7f0e0703400b  (unknown)  raise
(BroadModel pid=145826)     @     0x7f0e0735b420  (unknown)  (unknown)
(BroadModel pid=145826)     @                0x3  (unknown)  (unknown)
(BroadModel pid=145826) [2022-08-30 15:24:40,346 E 145826 145875] logging.cc:361: *** SIGABRT received at time=1661887480 on cpu 6 ***
(BroadModel pid=145826) [2022-08-30 15:24:40,346 E 145826 145875] logging.cc:361: PC: @     0x7f0e0703400b  (unknown)  raise
(BroadModel pid=145826) [2022-08-30 15:24:40,348 E 145826 145875] logging.cc:361:     @     0x7f0e0735b420  (unknown)  (unknown)
(BroadModel pid=145826) [2022-08-30 15:24:40,351 E 145826 145875] logging.cc:361:     @                0x3  (unknown)  (unknown)
(BroadModel pid=145826) Fatal Python error: Aborted
(BroadModel pid=145826) 
2022-08-30 15:24:40,556 WARNING worker.py:1829 -- A worker died or was killed while 
    executing a task by an unexpected system error. To troubleshoot the problem, check the logs for the dead worker. 
    RayTask ID: ffffffffffffffffb6fedc6726cbd809885e392701000000 Worker ID: f56690910b7de43cb69060607ad61467ac62cac906e7d85793d2c9a3 Node ID: 7321e7f004a736d6a59ac21c27271e98c304335e7828e7cb458b4599 
    Worker IP address: 10.37.0.16 Worker port: 45455 
    Worker PID: 145826 Worker exit type: SYSTEM_ERROR 
    Worker exit detail: Worker unexpectedly exits with a connection error code 2. 
    End of file. 
    There are some potential root causes. 
    (1) The process is killed by SIGKILL by OOM killer due to high memory usage. 
    (2) ray stop --force is called. 
    (3) The worker is crashed unexpectedly due to SIGSEGV or other unexpected errors.
```

I run this code on ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia GTX 1070 with 32 GB ram.

```
nvidia driver version = 515

cuda = 11.7

cudnn = 8.5

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               11.2.2              hbe64b41_10    conda-forge
cudnn                     8.1.0.77             h90431f1_0    conda-forge
cudnnenv                  0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
magma-cuda110             2.5.2                         1    pytorch
```